# Change bundle directory structure possible?

Tags: symfony, structure, bundle

Is this possible to change bundle structure in Symfony 2, for example:

- MyBundle

  - EntityName

    - Controller.php
    - Entity.php
    - EntityRepository.php
    - view

      - index.html.twig
      - etc
  - SecondEntity
  - etc

Is this possible and how can I start doing such thing?

Comment: Most I'am curious and that structure looks quite good for me, maybe even better than Sf2 convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

If you grep through the frame work code you find certain directory names are hard coded into the system.  I know you are trying to organize things by entity.  I used to do that myself for a number of projects.

But if you are going to use S2 then you need to embrace it's basic structure.  It works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [KnpRadBundle](http://rad.knplabs.com/). They changed the structure a bit.

But as Cerad said, some of the paths are hard coded due to consistency, which fabpot, creator of Symfony explains it [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3489#issuecomment-4340229).